# Launching a .exe Upon a Timer's Due_Date

Tags: python, date, datetime, python-2.7

How Would i Go About Adding a File To launch when it see that's it's the due_date? I've try'd quite i few different method's from Google but i'm still having a hard time figuring it out. currently it's set to wait 36 hours after launching the .py file.

any help would be great and it'd get this monkey off my back for good!

```
import datetime
import croniter
import crontab
import time

c = croniter.croniter("0 9,10,11 * * TUE")
next_due_date = c.get_next(datetime.datetime)


while True:
now = datetime.datetime.now()
    if now > next_due_date:
        do_something(line.py)
        time.sleep(60 * 60 * 36)
    else:
        time.sleep(60 * 60 * 2)
```

Comment: What is the issue exactly? Does the file not launch? or does it not launch properly?

Comment: The main issue is that i can get it to output it's date into the console but i'm not 100% on how to make the timer launch a .py or .exe at the end of the timer aka the due date

edit:btw im testing out your code just give me a bit to mess with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a .exe you can just use os.system("myexecutable.exe") after launching the python

```py
import datetime
import croniter
import crontab
import time

c = croniter.croniter("0 9,10,11 * * TUE")
next_due_date = c.get_next(datetime.datetime)


while True:
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    if now > next_due_date:
        do_something(line.py) # Edit: fixed tabbing; just in case it wasn't tabbed in 
                              #       your script
        # Use os.system to run the exe 
        os.system("myexecutable.exe")
        time.sleep(60 * 60 * 36)
    else:
        time.sleep(60) # Edit: I always find that it's better to have a smaller 
                       #       sleep time
```

You can also use the subprocess module so you can halt the script or track if the exe is still running instead.

Comment: What could be a good way to test this script ?
if i was to set it to the current time would my script(.exe) start immediately ?

Also do i have the Time Range's set up correctly?
i think it's set to 9-11am

Comment: @MattDweller - To test, you could skip the croniter step, and instead set next_due_date = datetime.datetime.today().replace(minute = datetime.datetime.today().minute.real + 1). This will set it to one minute in the future. And I believe you have everything setup correctly. I never used croniter, but when i checked it's value it was Next Tuesday at 9AM.